# How can I get n items of IPublishedContent in Umbraco 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, umbraco7

In my Umbraco app I need to get 3 news feed items on my homepage.

I am able to get the full list by doing:

`IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> newsItems = CurrentPage.newsRootPage.Children as IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>;`

I tried using Linq to get 3 items using the `Take` method:

`IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> newsItems = CurrentPage.newsRootPage.Children.Take(3) as IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>;`

but I get an exception saying:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'Take''

I have tried importing the Linq namespace at the top of the razor view (`@using System.Linq;`) but this doesn't help.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `(CurrentPage.newsRootPage.Children as IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>).Take(3)`?

Comment: Thank you! If you write out an answer I will accept it..

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't say so, I assume that `CurrentPage.newsRootPage.Children` is a List. Although a `List` implements `IEnumerable`, it doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

However, if you are certain that every child implements `IPublishedContent` you can easily convert your sequence to an `IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>`. This is done using [Enumerable.Cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx). After that you can use [Enumerable.Take](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> newsItems = CurrentPage.newsRootPage.Children
    .Cast<IPublishedContent>()
    .Take(3)
```